# In Factory Boy, how to join strings created with Faker?

Tags: python, faker, factory-boy

I want to use [Factory Boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [its support](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#realistic-random-values) for [Faker](http://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to generate strings from more than one provider. e.g. combining `prefix` and `name`:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)


# factories.py
import factory

class PersonFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person

    full_name = '{} {}'.format(factory.Faker('prefix'), factory.Faker('name'))
```

But this doesn't seem to work. e.g.:

```
>>> person = PersonFactory()
>>> person.full_name
'<factory.faker.Faker object at 0x7f25f4b09e10> <factory.faker.Faker object at 0x7f25f4ab74d0>'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the fields on your `models.Person` class?   This is relevant info.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure it would help, but I've added it now.

Comment: @PhilGyford: Does [this](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#lazy-attributes) work? You'd have to create a `prefix` and a `name` class attribute that don't exist in your model and then combine them to create `full_name`. I'm not sure if this will cause an error, as your original `Person` model doesn't have those fields.

Comment: @Blender Thanks, but I tried that, and did get an error for the reason you suggest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the (essentially undocumented) `exclude` attribute to make your first approach work:

```
class PersonFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('prefix', 'name')

    # Excluded
    prefix = factory.Faker('prefix')
    name = factory.Faker('name')

    # Shows up
    full_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda p: '{} {}'.format(p.prefix, p.name))
```

You could also just use `factory.LazyAttribute` and generate it all in one go by directly using `faker`:

```
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

class PersonFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    # Shows up
    full_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda p: '{} {}'.format(fake.prefix(), fake.name()))
```

The downside of this approach is that you you don't have easy access to the person's prefix or name.

Comment: Thanks! I thought maybe there was a way with `factory.LazyAttribute` but never managed to find quite the right combination of fakes.

Comment: Pretty good.  Only quibble is that you will generate transgender (in the literal sense of the word) names this way.