# How to use a Faker value as part of another field with FactoryBoy

Tags: python, faker, factory-boy

I'm using FactoryBoy and Faker to generate some models for unit tests.
Generating data for fields is easy enough, but how to I generate a string that incorporates a value produced from a Faker provider?

```
import factory
import MyModel

class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        # my_ip will be a temporary variable that is not returned by the factory.
        exclude = (my_ip,)

    my_ip = factory.Faker("ipv4_private")
    my_string = f"String with IP address [{my_ip}]"
```

Using MyFactory then creates objects with `my_string` set to something like:

`String with IP address [<factory.faker.Faker object at 0x7fc656aa6358>]`

How can I get `my_string` to contain something like:

`String with the IP address [192.168.23.112]`

How do I resolve this to a value, rather than just getting the object?
I've tried wrapping in str() with no luck. Do I need to use LazyAttribute or LazyFunction or something from FactoryBoy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some trial and error I figured out this did require using LazyAttribute so the my_string attribute is calculated after the rest of the object is generated.

However, I then discovered this is essentially a duplicate of: [In Factory Boy, how to join strings created with Faker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46099981/1477247)

If anyone is wondering, the way to do this is:

```
my_string = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: f"String with IP address [{o.my_ip}]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Params feature](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#parameters) of factory_boy to make the `my_ip` value available to `LazyAttribute` without factory_boy trying to set it on the model.

```py
import factory
import MyModel

class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    class Params:
        my_ip = factory.Faker("ipv4_private")

    my_string = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: f"String with IP address [{o.my_ip}]")
```